# Why No supported mechanism is available to create a library in C# using Xamarin.iOS that can be called from Objective-C.?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Query1:

It is mentioned on page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/embedded-frameworks?tabs=windows

It will not be possible to create embedded frameworks from any type of Xamarin.iOS projects, only consume existing native (Objective-C) frameworks.

Why it is not possible?

Query 2:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/objective-c-developers/primer

There is currently no supported mechanism to create a library in C# using Xamarin.iOS that can be called from Objective-C.

Please explain why it is not supported?

Comment: You can create a framework via Embeddinator-4000's objcgen that has mono embedded into the resulting ObjC framework and then consume it as a standalone framework.

Comment: @SushiHangover

 it is written in Xamarin Doc. is the Xamarin Doc not updated?

There is currently no supported mechanism to create a library in C# using Xamarin.iOS that can be called from Objective-C.

Please explain why it is not supported?

Comment: You are looking at a different type of "embedding", read that the Embeddinator/.Net Embedding docs, try starting here, work through the samples: https://github.com/mono/embeddinator-4000